# Forms: FormItem does not reappear based on if condition

Tags: forms, blazor, telerik, blazor-webassembly

I'm very new to blazor and web dev in general, have been struggling with this for a couple of days.
I changed the title of this, because the problem shifted.

I have a custom razor component, where I am using a [Telerik](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/radiogroup/events) radiogroup that is bound to an enum type object in my model e.g. Model.City.

```
<TelerikRadioGroup Data="@Data"
                           @bind-Value="@Model.City"
                           OnChange="@OnChangeHandler">
```

In my razor cs file, I have a boolean property (HasCinema), which is dependent on this enum value:

```
    HasCinema = Model.City is not (City.One or City.Two);
```

This property is set upon initialization (in OnInitialized()) and also of course re-set in the OnChangeHandler(object city).

```
async Task OnChangeHandler(object city) //is called 
    {
        HasCinema = city is not (City.One or City.Two);
        //StateHasChanged(); should not be needed when OnChangeHandler is a EventCallback

    }
```

In the html part of my razor component some way down I have the following if statement:

```
@if (HasCinema)
{
    <FormItem Field="@nameof(Model.Cinema)">
        <Template>
            <AnotherComponent For="@(() => Model.Cinema)" />

            <TelerikTextBox Id="state" Size="sm" Placeholder=""
            @bind-Value="@Model.Cinema"> </TelerikTextBox>
        </Template>
    </FormItem>
}
```

The idea is obviously this part only shows up and disappears depending on the selected city in the radiogroup.

I see that the boolean HasCinema successfully goes between True and False depending on the selected radio button and hence the bound value in the Model.

Current behaviour:
On the very initial render, if the default selected City produces a True for HasCinema, then the FormItem shows up as expected. When the user then chooses another City, that will produce a HasCinema == False, the component disappears, as expected. However, from then on it will not reappear again. So the transition from False ==> True does not seem to work anymore.

UPDATE:
Hey, thanks to @Rbee 's example I figured out the FormItem isn't showing up because I don't have an "else" statement. When I add an else block like so :

```
else 
{
     <p> blah blah </p>
}
```

it works, the FormItem and the paragraph change with changing True and False - although it does mess up the order of the FormItems for some reason. However, I need it to appear and disappear seamlessly, not to be replaced by another item?

Comment: Seems to be working as expected. [snippet link](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/mnksaUOc06IQ9AIC29). Perhaps there is some other issue. Can you share the rest of your code and/or recreate the problem in a snippet?

Comment: Hey, thanks to your example I figured out the FormItem isn't showing up because I don't have an "else" statement. When I add an else block with some <p> blah blah </p>, it works, the FormItem and the paragraph change with changing True and False.
So the FormItem can't just re-appear it seems once it's gone missing. More of an html problem than a Blazor problem I guess then? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the `visibility` css property of the `FormItem`.

```
<style>
    .hidden-item{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>

<FormItem Class="@(_hasCinema?"hidden-item":"")" Field="@nameof(Model.Cinema)">
    <Template>
        <AnotherComponent For="@(() => Model.Cinema)" />

        <TelerikTextBox Id="state" Size="sm" Placeholder=""
        @bind-Value="@Model.Cinema"> </TelerikTextBox>
    </Template>
</FormItem>
```

[Telerik Snippet](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/QnkMEqGR490gAZ9e49)

Don't forget to handle the case if/when the `Cinema` property is null.
Perhaps only rendering the item when it's not null.

Or, if you want the items to not take up space on the page then you can toggle the `display` css property

```
<style>
    .hidden-item{
        display:none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, this got me thinking on the right track, but unfortunately it isn't working for my code. I can't see any obvious differences between the snippet. I'll keep digging!